# How to Avoid Conditional Check Duplication

Tags: java

In the code, I am checking `altPhoneExist` and `altEmailExist` conditions multiple times. How can I avoid this and improve the performance and readability of the code?

***Code Description:***

A contact is created and added to a list if one of the conditions is true. And a different set operation executed for each one.

```
boolean altPhoneExist = contact.getAlternativePhoneNumber() != null;
boolean altEmailExist = contact.getAlternativeEmail() != null;

if (altPhoneExist || altEmailExist) {

    if (altPhoneExist) {
        contact.setPhoneNumber(contact.getAlternativePhoneNumber());
    }

    if (altEmailExist) {
        contact.setEmail(contact.getAlternativeEmail());
    }

    rqType.getContactInfoList().add(CraneFactory.createContactPerson(contact));
}
```

Comment: Make your question more clear please. Read [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review site, this site is quite different from Stack Overflow. The goal of this site is to help you improve your coding abilities and we generally don't answer how to questions. To provide a good review we need to see more of the code, not less. We need at least complete functions and preferably complete classes or programs. As pointed out by @ZoranJankov please read the help center on how to ask a good question.

Comment: This question lacks a lot of details. Moreover, it's too hypothetical

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The code given in the question is working and I want to improve its readability and performance by removing unnecessary conditional checks. It is a very simple question. Two people understood it and answered. I do not think it has missing points.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, there are not other good ways that I see to avoid this kind of logic; you can attenuate the [arrow code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) by inverting the first condition and returning early.

```java
if (!altPhoneExist && !altEmailExist) {
   return;
}

// Here we know it's either one of them


if (altPhoneExist) {
   contact.setPhoneNumber(contact.getAlternativePhoneNumber());
}

if (altEmailExist) {
   contact.setEmail(contact.getAlternativeEmail());
}

rqType.getContactInfoList().add(CraneFactory.createContactPerson(contact));
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use a flag without creating the temporary variables `altPhoneExist` and `altPhoneExist`:

```
boolean updated = false;
if(contact.getAlternativePhoneNumber() != null) {
    contact.setPhoneNumber(contact.getAlternativePhoneNumber());
    updated = true;
}
if(contact.getAlternativeEmail() != null) {
    contact.setEmail(contact.getAlternativeEmail());
    updated = true;
}
if (updated) {
    rqType.getContactInfoList().add(CraneFactory.createContactPerson(contact));
}
```